# Greatest zero of difference of two integer polynomials

Tags: analysis, polynomials

Suppose $p,q$ are distinct monic polynomials of degree $n$ with integer coefficients, whose zeros are all real and lie in $[-M,M]$.

What is a good upper bound on the greatest absolute value of a real zero of $p-q$?

In my application, $p$ and $q$ are the characteristic polynomials of two graphs, so characteristic polynomials of $\{0,1\}$ symmetric matrices with zero on the diagonal. In case that makes it easier.

Comment: The answer probably depends on what you mean by a *good upper bound*? For starters let's look at $p(x)=x^3-400x$ with zeros at $x=0,\pm20$, and compare with $q(x)=p(x)+(x-1000)$ with zeros $\approx2.53$,
$\approx -21.17$ and $\approx 18.64$ somewhat close to those of $p(x)$. Yet $q(x)-p(x)=x-1000$ has a large zero in comparison.  My guess is that the higher the degree $n$ the more you can play with the idea of using a $p(x)$ such that $p'(\alpha)$ is quite large at all the zeros $\alpha$ of $p(x)$.

Comment: ^ I meant to write $q(x)=p(x)-(x-1000)$ in case you were wondering about those zeros. Sorry about my failure to proofread. Needing to realize the polynomial as characteristic polynomials of a graph undoubtedly ruins such extreme sports.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Thanks, I expect the answer to be pretty large without the matrix restriction. But it is finite at least since there are only a finite number of integer polynomials for each $n$ and $M$.